# USB wifi adapter does not work

Tags: wifi, adapter

I'm using a desktop pc and I'm trying to install a usb wifi adapter, but it doesn't show up or do anything when I plug it in. The driver software doesn't recognize it either.
(802.11n)

[image]

Comment: Why don't you refer to support pages of your product. Perhaps, someone else already had this problem and hopefully they posted a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Operating System Cant Find Your USB Adapter . 
The Problem May Be Your Operating System Because It Is Obsolete Or
Your USB Adapter May Be Damaged .Test It On Another Computer .

Are You Can Install Windows Seven ? Instead Windows Xp .
Call Me At NarimanGtSari@Gmail.com To I Send Full Windows Seven Download Link .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It's Easy, Just Head Into The 'Device Manager' And Update The Connected USB Wifi Adapter (Not From Internet)... Just From Your PC, You Will Have To Click On Exsisting Update File And Wait Until It Installs Your Driver, Or You Must Have A CD Came With Your USB Wifi Adapter Product, It Contains The Drivers For All Platforms, Just Install Its Official Driver From The CD.

Comment: What's Up With The Capitalization Of The First Letter Of Each Word Here?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).